# Matplotlib heatmap with one color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to generate a heatmap like [this one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html).

I would like to have only one color, going from white where values are smaller to some other color when values are higher.

I tried setting cmap to one color, but the final result is still a map where I can see different colors (blue, red, etc..).

How can I do that? Also, do the values need to be within a specific range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give a *color map* to the `cmap` argument of [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).  E.g.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
imshow(A, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.Blues)
```

Color map samples: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

By default, the lowest and highest data values are mapped to the ends of the color range.  You can override this behavior by using the arguments `vmin` and `vmax` (or `norm`) of `imshow`.

Comment: is there also a valid range for these values, or will they be automatically normalized?

Comment: @Bob: I added a note about this to the answer.